# How to distribute apk files to my friends?

Tags: android

I have created a very small android app. I don't want to publish it to public. I just want my other friend to run my app on his phone. I don't have android phone but my friend has one. I have developed the app using eclipse IDE. How do I bundle it to apk and give it to him. I am a beginner (even less than a beginner) - please tell me what should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) (read from where it says Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT), then email him the apk! He'll need to put in on his phone's SD card and install it from there.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using Android Studio for application development.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to "build" from the navigation bar in Android Studio.
2. Go to "build bundle(s)/APK(s)" from the drop down that appears.
3. Click on "build APK(s)". You will get a notification box at the bottom right of your screen.
4. Click on "locate". Two files will appear. One is a "`.json`" file and one is an "`.apk`" file.
5. Send these files to your friends on WhatsApp and tell them to download the JSON file and install the APK file. Now your application is running.

You are done.

Answer (score 3):

If you email him the apk using it's gmail he can install it from within the gmail app opening the attachment :P.

Comment: Some times Gmail says: **Blocked for security reasons!** and you can't attach it

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html) to the android developer's documentation on other ways to share your app.

The easiest way to share an app is by sending it through e-mail. In order to share it via e-mail, you need to [prepare your app for release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html) and then attach it to the email and send it. After that , anyone receiving the email can instantly install the app through the click of a button.

Although there's many steps in creating the app the most important is [creating a keystore and a key for your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#generate-key) which will help you generate a signed app. Once you have the signed app you can also share the apk file by itself wherever needed, you're not restricted to sending it via e-mail. Make sure your friends have their setting set for installing apps from unknown sources

[image: menu option]

through the *Settings >> Security* menu.
If you need any more help let me know.

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using Android studio that's too simple,**

1. go to Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK (s).

Wait till the build is completed.

2. In the corner, you will see some like this screenshot. Click on Locate.

[image]

3. There in the opening folder, your app is located with the name

> app-debug.apk

*Share this app file with friends.*

**Note**: Friends may get a warning like this

[image]

tell them to click on

> INSTALL ANYWAY

You are done!

Comment: How to distribute APK files? not How to build APK files, @Vipul Chaudhary

Comment: distribute app-debug.apk bro @ManishRajpurohit

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio Menu Build > "Generate Signed APK". Follow the instructions on screen at the last step let yourself show the place where the release APK is placed (on my Mac it says "Show in Finder"). E-Mail that apk file to your friend. When an alert comes up that apps from unknown sources cannot be accepted the settings can be temporarily overridden and then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

1st In Android studio navigate to "Build" then generate a signed `.apk` (MUST USE `.APK`) If you want to share it without publishing it on google play. 2nd upload the  `.apk`
to your google drive, then on google drive right click the `.apk` then click on copy link. Last share and copy this link with any one or anywhere on the internet. If you want to trestrict to only few people go back to google drive right click on the `.apk` once again select or mention a category of people you will want to share with.

NOTE:
IF YOU SHARE THE LINK PUBLIC ON THE INTERNET WHENEVER SOMEONE OR ANYONE CLICK ON IT, IT WILL BE DOWNLOADED AUTOMATICALLY AND INSTALLED BY PACKAGE INSTALLER